# Error Code: ERROR ITMS-3000

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload the application on the iTunes Connect but I am facing a error [image: Link]

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The length of your "bundle version" is to long. The max amount is 100 and you have 102.